# SQLite: copy rows with a 'dynamic' field value

Tags: sql, sqlite

My first question here. I've been searching all over for an answer but I can't find it...

Here's the problem: I want to insert multiple records into a table (a sort of copy, but with some differences) I'm leaving the ID blank, so the auto increment will fill it, but I wanted to update a column (let's call it `field4`) with a different value for each result in a `SELECT`. Let me put this into code:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (field2,field3,field4) 
    SELECT 
        field2, field3,
        (SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE field2=200) 
    FROM 
        Table1 
    WHERE 
        field4 IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE field2=100)
```

This is resulting in correctly copying all rows, but the `field4` is always the same (first row from the `Select` query). I want it be all the values from the query for each row.

If this looks too confusing here's what I want to do: copy all rows (from table1) into table1 where the field2 in table2=100; but also, for each new row on table1 the field4 should be equal to the ID of each row from table2 where the field2 in table2=200.

Is this somehow possible?

SAMPLE DATA:

```
 TABLE1

 ID   field2   field3    field4
 ------------------------------
 1     1       text1     8
 2     2       text2     9
 3     1       text3     10
 4     2       text4     11
 12    1       text5     12
 140   1       text1     79
 141   2       text2     79
 142   1       text3     79
 143   2       text4     79
 144   1       text5     79

 TABLE2

 ID   field2   field3  
 --------------------
 8     100     text1     
 9     100     text2     
 10    100     text3     
 11    100     text4     
 12    100     text5     
 79    200     text100   
 80    200     text200   
 81    200     text300   
 82    200     text400   
 83    200     text500
```

if you notice, I successfuly copied the 5 bottom rows in table1 (they are copies from the 5 first rows in the same table), but the field4 is always the same (79) where it should be 79, 80, 81, 82, 83 (based of the query from table2).

Rewrote my description to be better understood.

I'm also new to SQL so, be gentle, and I'll try to explain myself as best as I can.

Comment: Your question makes little sense.  Sample data would help.

Comment: Your description mentions four different table names; your sample data, zero.